# Swift: How to calculate the size of a centered string

Tags: ios, swift, string

I currently calculate the size of a string as shown below. How can I do this calculation for a centered string?

```
func sizeOfString (string: String, constrainedToWidth width: Double, font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
    return (string as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                             options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                             attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
                                             context: nil).size
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "size of a centered string"? The size of a string that is centered should be the same as a string that's not centered.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, @Rob. Forgive me my senior moment. Something else must be effecting the result because the string goes to 2 lines approximately two characters before it is calculated as doing so. I should mention that the string is being set to the text of a label, which is in a collection view cell. The width I supply is that of the view, less the left and right section insets of the cell and the leading and trailing spaces of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> Something else must be effecting the result because the string goes to 2 lines approximately two characters before it is calculated as doing so.

Yes, the `boundingRect` will capture the size of the string if you render it yourself (e.g. with `draw(in:withAttributes:)`. But `UILabel` can conceivably be doing all sorts of other things (insetting in from the edges, etc.).

It strikes me that you have two basic options:

1. Nowadays, you'd grab the layout of the collection view flow layout and set its `itemSize` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` (in iOS 10 and later):

   ```
   let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
   layout.estimatedItemSize = ...
   ```

   Then the cell will be resized automatically based upon the auto layout constraints you have in the cell (e.g. fixed width for the label, allow intrinsic size control height, perhaps with size <= some max size).
2. If you want to calculate the `boundingRect` yourself, then you'd probably render it yourself with [`draw(in:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1529855-draw), too, avoiding any idiosyncratic behavior of what `UILabel` is doing behind the scenes:

   ```
   let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis leo convallis, euismod ipsum sed, lacinia diam. Nam sit amet justo id lacus blandit sodales id et."

   let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
   paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
   paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

   let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
       .font: font,
       .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
   ]

   let rect = string.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                  options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                  attributes: attributes,
                                  context: nil)

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
   string.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
   let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
   ```

   You can then use `image` and `rect` for a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C** version

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30];
NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
NSString *text = @"hello";
...
const CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];
```

**Swift** version:

```
extension String {
    func size(OfFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        return (self as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "hello world!"
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
let width = string.size(OfFont: font).width // size: {w: 98.912 h: 14.32}
```

Comment: He wants to specify a max width and figure out the height as lines wrap. The above only works for a single line of text.

Comment: That answer is not good for the original question but it is a really good answer for my needs. Tks